# Setting values to a new variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new variable in a data frame (making a new column). The value is calculated different for each observation so I used for loop for that. Lets say the new variable I'm trying to add to the data frame `REPLIC` is called `PL`

`REPLIC$PL <- for (i in 1:ncol(REPLIC)) if (REPLIC$FTR[i]=="D") { REPLIC$PL[i] <- REPLIC$f_of_bet[i]*starting_budget*REPLIC$max[i])} else { REPLIC$PL[i] <- REPLIC$f_of_bet[i]*starting_budget*-1}`

I have also tried using mutate

`REPLIC <- mutate(REPLIC, PL = for loop goes here)`

also tried apply function

`REPLIC$PL <- apply(REPLIC,1, for loop here)`

I'm new to R and I don't really get what I'm missing here. The only thing I've managed so far is to create `PL` values in global environment. I'd be really happy if anyone could instruct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use a loop here, everything can be done using vectors.
Since you didn't share anything about your data, I had to make some assumptions, please correct me if these are wrong.

```
#create fake data

starting_budget <- 1000

REPLIC <- data.frame(FTR = c(rep('D',5),rep('A',5)),f_of_bet = runif(10),max=runif(10))

> REPLIC
   FTR   f_of_bet       max
1    D 0.78590664 0.3620227
2    D 0.15498935 0.4921082
3    D 0.20469729 0.5597419
4    D 0.01167919 0.3677215
5    D 0.32862533 0.5531767
6    A 0.52029750 0.5391566
7    A 0.63206626 0.9727405
8    A 0.54632605 0.7221810
9    A 0.58939969 0.6103260
10   A 0.15375445 0.1996567
```

The following code will add your new column. I'm using `ifelse` since you have a condition on `FTR`:

```
REPLIC$PL <- ifelse(REPLIC$FTR == 'D',
                    REPLIC$f_of_bet * starting_budget * REPLIC$max,
                    REPLIC$f_of_bet * starting_budget * -1)
```

This gives you:

```
> REPLIC
   FTR   f_of_bet       max         PL
1    D 0.78590664 0.3620227  284.51602
2    D 0.15498935 0.4921082   76.27153
3    D 0.20469729 0.5597419  114.57764
4    D 0.01167919 0.3677215    4.29469
5    D 0.32862533 0.5531767  181.78787
6    A 0.52029750 0.5391566 -520.29750
7    A 0.63206626 0.9727405 -632.06626
8    A 0.54632605 0.7221810 -546.32605
9    A 0.58939969 0.6103260 -589.39969
10   A 0.15375445 0.1996567 -153.75445
```

Comment: Oh wow! didn't think solution could be so simple. didn't know about ifelse function untill now. Thanks a lot!! and btw - regarding the for loop, do I need to also use `break` somewhere or it just stops after completing the dataframe?

Comment: A for loop will finish once it iterated over all elements it got as input (in your case `1:ncol` will loop over all column indexes. If you add a `break`, the loop will stop entirely at the point it is encountered.